# Are we obligated in an extra Chatas?

Tags: korban, derabanan, nozir

I am predicating this on two ideas:

1. That a person can be obligated now to bring a korban in the [future](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/25635), the way a convert today will be required to bring a korban when moshiach comes.
2. A [Nazir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40566/1362) brings a chatas to atone for his having made something allowed to him by Hashem, [forbidden](https://hamodia.com/columns/the-nazirs-sin/) to him.

   > The Gemara (Nedarim 10a) also questions why the nazir must offer a korban chatas, and it answers that the sin he committed was his original decision to needlessly cause himself suffering by abstaining from wine. After the Gemara states clearly that voluntarily refraining from physical enjoyment is considered sinful...

from Nedarim 10a

> ומה זה שלא ציער עצמו אלא מן היין נקרא חוטא המצער עצמו מכל דבר, על אחת כמה וכמה מכאן כל היושב בתענית נקרא חוטא

If so, does our behavior outside of Israel, refraining from melacha (the lack of which which might cause tza'ar moreso than just not drinking wine) on a day which is not a holiday (because we hold Yom Tov Sheini Shel Galuyos), obligate us in the future to a korban chatas? Is this self-imposed stricture similar to the vow a Nazir takes? In fact, do the various "syags", the gezeirot/takanot and fences enacted rabbinically which stop me from doing something which might be allowed textually all rise to that same level and would all obligate me to a future chatas?

Comment: To apply chachamim commandments is not a choice for us lo tasuru midivrehem Yamin usmol

Comment: I also read "The Mishnah says that once a law (takknakah or gezeirah) is legislated by the proper authorities *and accepted by the Jewish community at large*" (I added the *). Does this mean that if people don't accept it it isn't normative and binding, and if so, following it is the same sort of self-imposed choice?

Comment: Additionally, the svara of nazir chote is an explanattion of the pasuk, without pasuk nobody would bring Chatat for this

Comment: @rosends yes, if the Jewish people reject a Rabinic enactment at the time of its enactment as too difficult to keep etc. then it falls off and is no longer an obligation. However, if the decree survived the Talmud and proceding generation, then we all keep it until today and may not shirk it off. An example of a failed decree, AFAIK, would be the decree of Ezra , not to wash laundry on Friday.

Answer (score 4):

In nazir the Korban Chatat is writen in Torah. Chachamim give an explanation, but we cannot infer from the explanation that all such deprivation engender a Chyuv Chatat. Korban chatat follows precise rules. The Gemara you quoted from Nedarim 10a (also in Nazir 19a) says that a fortiori a man who deprivales himself is called sinner, but not regarding Korban Chatat. The words of the Gemara are accurate.