# Why was the Nazarite commanded to offer up an offering for sin?

Tags: halacha

Why was someone who performed a Nazarite vow obligated under the law to perform a sin offering.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40558/nazir-and-korban-chatas